# Access specific folder on FTP with PHP

Tags: php

Im using below code to download an .csv file from an ftp. which works if the file is placed in root - but I need to access it on a subfolder. How do I do this?

```
$source = "myfile.csv";
$target = fopen("myfile.csv", "w");
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.mysever.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"user","pass");
ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);
echo "file downloaded.\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify full path to folder in which file is.

```
$source = "path".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."to".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."subfolder".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."myfile.csv";
$target = fopen("myfile.csv", "w");
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.mysever.com") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"user","pass");
ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);
echo "file downloaded.\n";
```

Comment: *FYI* when using backward-slash you actually escaping `t`,`s` and `m`, same as you would write `\t\r\n` in double quoted string and converting it to `tab`, `new-line`

Comment: Hmm - I can´t get that to work. Do i need to use an absolut path or something? `Tried $target = fopen("subfolder\myfile.csv", "w");`

Comment: Edited answer; please check.

Comment: Hi @DivyeshPrajapati - cant get it to work - I changed subfolder to the subfolder on root, do I need change the other directory separators as well?

Comment: from root; in which folder your file is?

Comment: That's great :)